# openGL vs openCL in a GLUT application?

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl

I've never done GPU acceleration before, but I discovered that 50% of my runtime is in this function:

```
typedef std::array<uint16_t, NUMBER_CHEMICALS> Chemical_t;
std::vector<Chemical_t> chemical, next, emitters;

void FluidGrid::diffuse(float dt)
{
    const int N = (squares.x-1)*(squares.y-1);
    const int w = squares.x;

    for(int i = w; i < N; ++i)
    {
//store as integer 0-255 b/c bulldozer doesn't have multiple FPUs
        uPoint2B rate = diffusionRate[i];

        for(int k = 0; k < NUMBER_CHEMICALS; ++k)
        {
            int temp   = (chemical[i-1][k] + chemical[i+1][k])*rate.x
                       + (chemical[i-w][k] + chemical[i+w][k])*rate.y;
            next[i][k] = std::max((temp >> 8) + emitters[i][k], 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Luckily it seems like a good candidate for GPU acceleration, I want to know if there would be some problem using openCL and openGL in the same application, because both are using the same resources, or if this computation should be moved to the rendering thread so all the GPU contexts are in a single thread.

Is there any reason to use openGL rather than openCL to accelerate this, given that there is already a GL context? Or is this not a good candidate for acceleration, because it's likely memory rather than CPU bottlenecked?

Comment: if its going to be in opencl, solving for each chemical one after another would use cache better, more neighbor cells fit in cache this way. Maybe even better for cpu.